# What is the difference between explain('executionStats') and plain explain()

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I see that they return the exact same thing, why use one over the other then?

The code:

```
const explainQuery = collection.find().sort({last_modified:-1}).limit(1);
const researchQuery = collection.find().sort({last_modified:-1}).limit(1);
const explain = explainQuery.explain('executionStats');
researchQuery.toArray(function(err, data) {
    func(err, data, explain);
})
```

[image]

Comment: Which library you are using? There is a difference between the commands when you execute it in the mongo shell, but the library you are using may have some default settings to request execution stats implicitly. Add the code you are using to retrieve the output, and please, don't use images when plain copy-pasted text is sufficient.

Comment: Sounds like you have something wrapping the underlying `cursor.explain()` call because the default verbosity mode is "queryPlanner" not "executionStats". See [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain).

Comment: Using express. Btw, I would've not pasted images, but the question was too short, and there isn't a humane way to copy/paste text from WIN cmd.

Comment: Express is a js framework. Are you using Mongoose?  The way to copy text from win cmd is to press left mouse button, drag mouse to select text, release the button and press <Enter>. Does anything stop you to post the code you are using to retrieve the output?

Comment: You can see the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48112847/mongodb-why-cant-i-explain-and-return-a-query-using-one-variable

Comment: I have updated the question for you this time, but you should really learn how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. All required information should be included in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

[explain](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#explain) accepts a single optional argument which is a callback function. The string you are passing is ignored, and the function returns a Promise: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.2/lib/cursor.js#L1067

It seems the value `allPlansExecution` is hardcoded in the driver https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/fa0fbc0c4966dfaaf76f35c4de2e80876f53e825/lib/apm.js#L424.